# Can't Make a Tag in Tortoise Svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I try to make a tag I get this error

[image]

I am don't understand what it means.

This is what Ankh gives me

```
SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: Commit failed (details follow): ---> SharpSvn.SvnSystemException: could not begin a transaction
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, SvnException error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClientArgs.HandleResult(SvnClientContext client, svn_error_t* error, Object targets)
   at SharpSvn.SvnClient.Commit(ICollection`1 paths, SvnCommitArgs args, SvnCommitResult& result)
   at Ankh.Services.PendingChanges.PendingChangeHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1b.<Commit_CommitToRepository>b__19(Object sender, ProgressWorkerArgs e)
   at Ankh.ProgressRunnerService.ProgressRunner.Run(Object arg)
```

Comment: How do you connect to the repository? Are you able to commit otherwise? Can you do it via the command-line?

Comment: Have not tried command line, I am using a svn hosting company, other repositories connect fine.

Comment: Have you contacted your host?